# Using static instead of malloc - C-language

Tags: c, pointers, static, malloc

In my window app made in c (using gtk) I first had to make a pointer to pointer that I sent to a callbackfunction.

Since i sent the pointer to another function I thought I had to allocate memory on the heap for it that is:

```
  GtkWidget **entry;
  entry = malloc(5 * sizeof(GtkWidget));

  entry[0] = entry_a;
  entry[1] = entry_s;
  entry[2] = entry_t;
  entry[3] = entry_v;
  entry[4] = entry_r;
```

the GtkWidget variable is a local variable

But someone told my that this is not neccessary since it could be declared as static instead

```
  static GtkWidget *entry[5];
```

correct - the program works using a static GtkVidget-pointer instead. My question is **why** and **what** does this static mean in *this context*?

Comment: Depends. Is the variable inside of a function, or is it global in the source file (not part of any function)?

Comment: Just a quick unrelated note, do you perhaps mean `sizeof(GtkWidget*)` instead?

Comment: @cobbal - no it is as shown above - sizeof(GtkWidget)

Comment: @user3155478 I believe @cobbal is trying to tell you that you might have a bug (i.e. probably allocating too much memory). Also, if `static` is used outside of function scope, it means the declaration is only visible to the translation unit (file) you're in. If it's inside a function, `static` means the data is allocated in a different place that persists your data through different function calls.

Comment: The first program fragment contains a type error. Its intent is unclear. It is hard to tell whether the second one is correct, or contains a similar error. More context is needed.

Comment: @n.m. - the callbackfunction has to receive a pointer - thats why I had to make a pointer to pointer. When using [] it means that the pointer to pointer is derefferenced to a pointer. Am I correct? All the same - what does type-error mean? All I can tell is that it compiles fine. If the program inherits a memory leak - I dont know that by now? I update my question to show what entry is used for.

Comment: In this context `static` effectively means that the storage is like a global variable.  The potential downsides to this are the same as for global variables: multiple invocations of your code will get the same address as the last call (which in some cases you might not want), it is not thread-safe unless you add extra synchronization, etc.

Comment: @asveikau - does this implicate that its better to allocate the vector on the heap using malloc? Then free memory using free(entry).

Comment: If you want to allocate space for an array of 5 pointers, you need to allocate 5 times the size of the pointer type. In this case, the pointer type is `GtkWidget*`, so rather than `malloc(5 * sizeof(GtkWidget))` you'd want `malloc(5 * sizeof(GtkWidget*))`. An idiom that avoids errors like this is: `entry = malloc(5 * sizeof *entry)`

Comment: Not all type errors are found by the compiler. Some are masked by `void*` and casts. You cannot possibly be correct because the size of what you allocate does not match the type that you use. You need either an array of 5 pointers, in this case allocate `5*sizeof(GtkWidget*)`, or an array of 5 widgets, in this case use `GtkWidget *entry;`.

Answer (score 0):

All variables with a `static` storage class will have a program execution lifetime and internal linkage; its scope, however, depends on where it is declared.

To address the question you asked, whether to use a `static` array or `malloc`ing an array is really something that must determined on a case by case basis.  For the most part, however, memory is cheap, so you shouldn't have to worry about performance issues one way or the other, unless your array size becomes excessive (an `int` array size of 5 is rather insignificant).  Protecting the integrity of an array is much more of a concern.  That is why, as a rule of thumb, you should make a variable's scope as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

They do different things.

If you allocate an array (or any object) using `malloc`, that memory is allocated at run time when `malloc` is called, and it continue to exist until `free` it (i.e., pass the pointer value returned by `malloc` to the `free` function). (`realloc` can also deallocate `malloc`ed space, but that's not relevant here.)

If you define an array object using the `static` keyword, then the object exists during the entire run time of your program.

The meaning of the `static` keyword is different depending on where it appears. On a local declaration (inside a function), it gives the object static storage duration, meaning that it exists for the entire execution of the program rather than being deallocated when the function returns. This means it can retain its previous value across calls to the function. An object defined outside any function already has static storage duration; in that case, the `static` keyword changes its *linkage*, so it's not visible from other source files.

Which is better, static allocation or `malloc`? It's impossible to say without more information.

`malloc` is more flexible. It will report an allocation failure by returning a null pointer; if you declare a static object that's too big, chances are your program will just crash. For an array of just 5 pointers, though, you probably don't need to worry about that (nevertheless, you should *always* check the value returned by `malloc`).

Defining a `static` object only lets you define a single object for each name. `malloc` lets you build dynamic structures. It also lets you decide at run time how many elements an array needs.

A third alternative is to define an object locally, inside some function definition, without the `static` keyword. In that case the object will exist only inside that function (or even inside a block), and will be automatically deallocated when the function returns.

Without knowing what you're going to do with your pointer array, we can't tell you how it should be declared and allocated. If you can declare it as a local variable inside some function, you probably should. If you can't, well, don't.